# Importing users via powershell true CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2016

hey every one im having trouble trying to create new user via powersheel with the help of a csv file, im not getting any wiser out of this error.

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Vroege" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Late" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
#importing modules
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$filepad = Read-Host -Prompt "vul hier het pad in waar de file zig bevind"

$users = Import-Csv $filepad

#LOOP
foreach ($user in $users) {
    #info verzammelen

    $Fname = $user.'First Name'
    $Lname = $user.'Last Name'
    $Officephone = $user.'Office Phone'

    $jtitle = $user.'Job Title'
    $OUpath = $user.'Orgianizational Unit'
    $Password = $user.Password

    #creating users
    New-ADUser -Name "$Fname $Lname" -GivenName $Fname -Surname $Lname -UserPrincipalName "$Fname.$Lname@mvdb.test" -Path $OUpath -AccountPassword ( ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force ) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -OfficePhone $Officephone -Enabled $True 


    #echo output

    echo "de account zijn aangemaakt voor $fname $Lname in $OUpath"

    }
```

and this is the error im getting the idea is to import users from a CSV file, direct on the

```
 New-ADUser : No superior reference has been configured for the directory service. The directory service is therefore unable 
to issue referrals to objects outside this forest
At C:\Users\mikevdb_admin\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:22 char:5
+     New-ADUser -Name "$Fname $Lname" -GivenName $Fname -Surname $Lnam ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Wes Sieders,OU=Late:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8406,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: Lots of grammar errors there.. I think it would be wise if you read more about the subject. Examples of working code are not hard to find, like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24541.powershell-bulk-create-ad-users-from-csv-file.aspx) or [there](https://activedirectorypro.com/create-bulk-users-active-directory/). As tip: do `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` BEFORE you use any AD cmdlets and check [New-ADOrganizationalUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adorganizationalunit?view=win10-ps) and its parameters.

Comment: Sidenote: instead of copying to local variables I'd use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that my specification of the -OU path was wrong.   After reading many posts, including the two in comment #2 above, I
was still unable to configure a combination that worked.

Fortunately I found some useful information in the link labeled "there" in comment 2.
https://activedirectorypro.com/create-bulk-users-active-directory/

In the video, the person mentions that specifying the -OU parameter is optional.

I removed the -OU parameter from the script and it ran, creating the users in Users.

Doing it this way is probably only useful for small companies.

If you get this error, look very closely at your OU values.  The problem may also be related to passing in a field that has commas in a .csv file.  I suspect that when you export data from Excel as a .csv, it quotes the fields, which might solve the comma problem.